expo push notifications "google-services.json" is missing for firebase
I am trying to setup push notifications for my expo react native app.
Running in expo go everything works fine.
Now for production I followed this Expo GUIDE.
The first 4 steps of this guide are reasonable.
But step 5 is very confusing:

first of all, suddenly there is an app in the console, but there was no instruction to create one. So I just added one, with the same package name as in my app.json.
Then it explains where to place the google-service.json file, how to reference it in the app.json and to put it into .gitignore. Which I have done.

a) But this results in a warning: File specified via "android.googleServicesFile" field in your app.json is not checked in to your repository and won't be uploaded to the builder.
b) and finally in a failed build: "google-services.json" is missing, make sure that the file exists. Remember that EAS Build only uploads the files tracked by git. Use EAS secrets to provide EAS Build with the file.
So do I have to put the content of the google-services.json file into an EAS secret? even though the guide mentions nothing about doing this and even says You're all set! You can now send notifications to Android devices via Expo Push Notifications using the FCM V1 protocol. ?

Expo isn't really in my domain, but the documentation you linked is generic and assumes you've previously configured your project and only need to deal with Firebase CM. Thus it does not cater to the specifics about how to load google-services.json (which is instead covered by the EAS Build environment variables FAQ). If this works for you, ping me here, and I'll hydrate it as an answer.

I encountered in the same issue and I solved in 3 steps:
Step 1:
Rename app.json file to app.config.js Note: use module exports to set the config the right way in .js file example:
module.exports = {
   expo: {
     //...rest of the configurations
    android: {
      //...rest of the configurations
      googleServicesFile: process.env.GOOGLE_SERVICES_JSON,
     },
   }
 }

Step 2:
Add the file google-services.json into the project root folder.
Step 3:
Run this command in the project root directory
eas env:create --scope project --name GOOGLE_SERVICES_JSON --type file --value ./google-services.json

Make sure if ./google-services.json is the actual path to your google-services.json file.

Thank you. Is this documented anywhere? @Anas

This was documented in the Expo documentation; however, upon checking after your inquiry, it appears they have removed it, and I'm not sure why.

After uploading the secret and doing all the steps you talked about I also faced the same issue.
So I went through this issue on github (eas build fails because build file cannot be found: Firebase config files saved in expo secrets not being transferred correctly #1821)
So what I did was to copy the contents of app.json file in the root directory to a new app.config.js file
/// app.config.js
export default { 
    expo: {
         ..., 
         android: {
             ..., 
             googleServicesFile: process.env.GOOGLE_SERVICES_JSON || "./google-services.json",
             ...
         },...
    }
 }

I also deleted the app.json. Not sure if it was necessary.
And I was able to build successfully.

Back in the days we used expo go as well for our project and yes, the google service json was in the repo.

putting the file into the repo works. But I will not mark your answer as the correct one, because I will check on @samthecodingman s response in the next couple of days. His response seems like the more secure and thus sensible one.

The file google-services.json should be in android/app and can't be in .gitignore. You can set google-services.json as expo secret in your project expo.dev. I am using my expo secret GOOGLE_SERVICES_JSON. To get variable i am using "googleServicesFile": ${process.env.GOOGLE_SERVICES_JSON} in file app.config.ts. See: How to upload a secret file and use it in my app config?
